# Make app not open on push notification clicking

Tags: objective-c

I am developing an app which enables pushNotification.When the app in inactive mode it receives push notification.When user click push notification app is opening.I do not want to open the app on push notification clicking.Is it possible do so?thanks in advance

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of someone trying to *reduce* user engagement :)

Comment: On iOS, I don't think that you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Why do you want to do it anyway? You should probably use sound notification instead of banner/alert if you don't want user interaction.

Comment: use `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound` in `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`

Comment: I have set badgevalue for app icon.Without notification can i display count of badgevalue?

Comment: Yes, badge count is displayed on app icon, so you don't need banner notification type for updating badge count.

Comment: can u give some example?I have no idea how to implement ur idea?

Comment: Ok - update your question with your exact requirement and show my your existing code - how are you registering for push notification and how are you sending push notification from server?